# Common expression for starting grammar school later than expected

Tags: expressions

There's a expression for children who go to school one year later than their peers, because they are deemed not yet ready, in Hungary this is at age 6 after kinder-garden, and they could wait with grammar school for one more year. (Hungarian word "évvesztes")

Do you have a similar word in English, or would this be just described, as "oh, I went to school one year late"? Could "deferred" be used in this context, or is that just for higher education applicants' admission postponing?

Comment: Grammar school starts at 11 years old. You're talking about either elementary or primary school.

Comment: I've never heard of grammar school at all. (Canada.) Some schools may have courses where the subject is grammar, but that word isn't used for school in general. As for being in school a year later, I've heard the expression *held back*. But that's normally only used if there is a learning problem. Some people, born on December 31, for instance, will end up being a year older than everybody—they would not be considered to have been *held back*, but it would simply be an *accident* of their date of birth.

Comment: Actually, where I'm from "grammar school" is grades K through 5.  Middle school starts at grade 6.  High school (also known as secondary school) starts at grade 9 and of course finishes with the completion of grade 12.  Some nearby school districts have what's called "junior high," which is grades 7 and 8, leaving high school the same but making grammar school not end until the completion of grade 6 (a.k.a., "the 6th grade").

Answer (score 2):

The alternative words used is determined by local authority terminology.

I live in Hampshire, England; and we have 2 words for *évvesztes* which mean different things.

You have [deferred entry](https://www.hants.gov.uk/educationandlearning/admissions/applicationprocess/changeorlateapplication/startingschool#step-1) where you can defer entry to a later part of the year, or you have [decelerated entry](https://www.hants.gov.uk/educationandlearning/admissions/applicationprocess/changeorlateapplication/summerborn) where you can defer entry for a whole year, but that is only allowed in exceptional circumstances.

I don't know if this applies everywhere in England, but it does in Hampshire.